# Equal width columns with a "gap-X" applied using Tailwind and flex-wrap utility

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Haven't found an actual solution for this yet on SO.

I'm looking to have a set of equal-width columns using Tailwind. I am using Flexbox and can achieve what I want, while maintaining Responsiveness (important!) using the code below:

```
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full">
    <!-- Columns -->
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 2xl:w-1/4 dark:bg-zinc-950">
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 2xl:w-1/4 dark:bg-zinc-950">
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 2xl:w-1/4 dark:bg-zinc-950">
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 2xl:w-1/4 dark:bg-zinc-950">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm struggling with is now I'd like to put a "flex-wrap" on that outer div to keep the responsiveness working, but as soon as I add that class, the last column (at any media query size) immediately wraps. So like, if 3 columns should be showing, it shows 2, with a large empty space where column 3 should be because it wrapped already.

I've seen a number of solutions using Grid, the code above, or similar, but NONE of them maintain/allow for responsiveness. How can I achieve this?